# Count the occurrence of elements in every row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

[image]

The dataframe has eleven columns with each of them having a grade assigned to them. For each record, I need to count the number of `A`s, `B`s and `C`s in it.

This is what my intended output should look like

[image]

I tried doing this using the `apply` function. This is what I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
# sample data
df_dict = {'level_1': {0: 'C', 1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: 'C', 6: 'A', 7: 'B', 8: 'B'},
           'level_2': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'C', 6: 'B', 7: 'C', 8: 'A'},
           'level_3': {0: 'B', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'B', 8: 'C'},
           'level_4': {0: 'A', 1: 'C', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'B', 5: 'C', 6: 'A', 7: 'B', 8: 'C'},
           'level_5': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'A'},
           'level_6': {0: 'C', 1: 'C', 2: 'C', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'A', 8: 'C'},
           'level_7': {0: 'C', 1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'C', 7: 'A', 8: 'A'},
           'level_8': {0: 'B', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'C'},
           'level_9': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'B', 6: 'A', 7: 'C', 8: 'B'},
           'level_10': {0: 'B', 1: 'C', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'C'},
           'level_11': {0: 'C', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'C', 8: 'B'}
           }
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

# function to count the values of A, B, C
def count_in_df(series):
    _ = series.value_counts()
    _ = _[['A', 'B', 'C']]
    return _.tolist()

count_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_df.apply(count_in_df, axis=1).tolist(),
                       columns=['counts_of_A', 'counts_of_B', 'counts_of_C'])

# add count information back 
sample_df = sample_df.join(count_df)
```

This gives me the information I need but the problem is that the code is too slow. I have about 700k records and 66 columns(instead of 11) across which I need to perform this operation and it took me about 30 minutes to get the results.

Is there a way I can speed up the code? Any optimizations that I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack` + `groupby` + `value_counts` for something simple. Rename the columns then append back.

```
df = (sample_df
      .stack()
      .groupby(level=0)
      .value_counts()
      .unstack(1)
      .add_prefix('counts_of_')
     )

df = pd.concat([sample_df, df], axis=1)
```

#### Output: `df`

```
   count_of_A  count_of_B  count_of_C
0           2           5           4
1           4           4           3
2           2           4           5
3           4           4           3
4           4           4           3
5           3           4           4
6           5           3           3
7           4           4           3
8           3           3           5
```

Comment: Nice! Added a solution with add_prefix and assign based on yours. +1

Comment: Ah good point. It's nice that it allows you to chain, though my recollection is that it winds up copying the entire DataFrame just to rename the columns, which can be slow.

Comment: This is beautiful. Runs in a minute. Thank you.

Comment: @ALollz, if you don't mind could you explain why this is so much faster?

Comment: @ALollz You have a point. I removed the solution and integrated add_prefix to yours which gave a minor speed boost. (very minor).

Answer (score 2):

I use `str.get_dummies`

```
sample_df.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)

Out[142]:
   A  B  C
0  2  5  4
1  4  4  3
2  2  4  5
3  4  4  3
4  4  4  3
5  3  4  4
6  5  3  3
7  4  4  3
8  3  3  5
```

Comment: That's lit! Crazy one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @ALollz is good. But my approach would be something like this.

```
>>> dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(sample_df)
>>> sample_df['count_of_A'] = dummy_df.filter(regex='level_(\d+)_A').sum(axis=1)
>>> sample_df['count_of_A']
0    2
1    4
2    2
3    4
4    4
5    3
6    5
7    4
8    3
```

Similarly, if you have multiple `grades`.

```
>>> grades = list('ABC')
>>> for grade in grades:
...     sample_df[f'count_of_{grade}'] = dummy_df.filter(regex=f'level_(\d+)_{grade}').sum(axis=1)
... 
>>> sample_df.filter(regex='count_of_')
   count_of_A  count_of_B  count_of_C
0           2           5           4
1           4           4           3
2           2           4           5
3           4           4           3
4           4           4           3
5           3           4           4
6           5           3           3
7           4           4           3
8           3           3           5
```